# кодировка - пїЅпїЅпїЅ - помогите!

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка

Переводил систему из Windows-1251 в UTF-8.
И как-то запутался (стартовал другой проект, ночь не спал).
Теперь во всей системе: `пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ`
Бэкапа нет, так как это и есть исходники.
Что это за беда с этими кодировками?
Как теперь быть?
Что можно сделать?
———————
P.S. В HEX-редакторе тоже всё `EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF`
Это всё? Это конец?

Comment: @I_CaR Если и в hex'е `BD EF`, то это конец...Если очень повезёт, выцарапаете старые удалённые файлы чем-нибудь типа Recuva...

Comment: @kff Про это я уже подумал. Но самое ведь страшное, что фалы не удалялись, а перезаписывались.

Comment: @I_CaR если конвертирование происходило в phpstorm там есть локальная история. Чтобы подобное никогда не повторилась начните использовать GIT. На codecademy недавно появился вводный курс.